# substitute function(x) with f(x) in javascript-mode emacs

Tags: javascript, emacs, elisp

I am new to emacs and emacs-lisp so i don't have any idea how to write extensions to emacs but i came accross awesome extensions like 'pretty-lambdas' which swaps

```
(lambda (x) (+ x x)) ---->  (λ (x) (+ x x))
```

In emacs-lisp mode. I was able to make it work for clojure such that i get :

```
(fn [x] (+ x x)) ----->     (λ [x] (+ x x))
```

I would like to do the same for javascript, such that In javascript mode instead of

```
function(x){}
```

I get .  ***f(x) {}***

how do i achieve this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never used pretty lambdas, but there are a number of other libraries that can do this.

In Emacs 24.4, there is a new built-in mode called `prettify-symbols-mode`. You should be able to do something like

```
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (push '("function" . ?ƒ) prettify-symbols-alist)
            (prettify-symbols-mode)))
```

Thanks to Stefan, who [points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733253/substitute-functionx-with-fx-in-javascript-mode-emacs/25733680?noredirect=1#comment40256423_25733680) that there is also `global-prettify-symbols-mode`, in case you want to enable this mode all the time.

Alternatively, you could use [`pretty-mode`](https://github.com/akatov/pretty-mode), [`pretty-symbols`](https://github.com/drothlis/pretty-symbols) or [`purty-mode`](https://github.com/hackscience/purty-mode), all available in [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/), and `pretty-mode` is also in MELPA stable.

Something like this should work for `purty-mode`:

```
(purty-add-pair '("\\(\\bfunction\\b\\)" . "ƒ"))
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook #'purty-mode)
```

Note that `purty-mode` only seems to have a single replacement table, so the `function` → `ƒ` replacement will affect all buffers where `purty-mode` is active.

Comment: when I am editing javascript files my emacs shows, the mode as Javascript not js. So my purty-add-pair seems to not work. so I still don't have "function" . "ƒ" working. However, I like purty.

Comment: Regarding `prettify-symbols-mode`, it is worth noting that there is also a `global-prettify-symbols-mode` you can activate once and for all in your `~/.emacs`.